# Unity 2D sprite render sproblem in final built project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have Unity 2D project. When I play it in unity editor, all is ok. But if I build a project and run it as a file, I have problems with sprites - when a character is moving, triangle parts of sprites are disappearing or getting white. How can I fix it?
I've tried to change different settings in the inspector, like wrap mode or other. Also, I added 1px border to sprites, but it did not work. Do you have some advice?
Here is an image of what I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzW4P.jpg